# How can I run a test with a specific configuration from the IDE in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, testing, android-espresso, android-testing

Very new to testing in Android so apologies in advance. I am wondering if there is a way to launch a test (e.g. ui-test) from the Android Studio IDE i.e the play button next to a class, but specify a custom configuration?

What i'm trying to achieve is:

- Run a test with Locale A
- Run a test with Locale B
- Run other configs typically with different launch environment or args

It doesn't neccessarily have to be by the play-button UI, just needs to be simple ideally.

Really appreciate anyone pointing me in the right direction! Would love to hear how people might approach this as well if you haven't.
Regards!

### **Current** - Example of Andoid Studio IDE test-run UI

[image: Example of Andoid Studio IDE test-run UI]

### **Desired** - Example of Xcode IDE test-run UI

In Xcode, I can set my configuration files, and the UI prompts me which one I want to run the test with.

[image: Example of Xcode IDE test-run UI]

Answer (score 0):

There is `Build Variants` on the left pane, you can set it first and run your tests.

[image]

Comment: @rye have you checked this